# How to downgrade Terraform major version in state file?

Tags: terraform, terraform-state

I'm using Terraform and accidentally changed the version in the state file from **v0.11.14** to **v1.0.10** while playing around with upgrading Terraform.

```
Initializing the backend...

Error:
Terraform doesn't allow running any operations against a state
that was written by a future Terraform version. The state is
reporting it is written by Terraform '1.0.10'

A newer version of Terraform is required to make changes to the current
workspace.
```

The state file is stored in AWS storage and is decrypted.

I read about solutions between minor versions but couldn't find a solution for downgrading from a major version back to **v0.11.14** :(

I was under the impression that `terraform init` won't touch the state file.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to downgrade, except to manually import all resources to old tf version.

Comment: Hey @Marcin You mean manually updating the old state file? Not sure what you mean by "import".

thx

Comment: Are you using S3 backend? If so and If you enabled versioning you can retrieve an old version?

Comment: Hi @MohammedYahya
The previous people responsible for Terraform didn't enable versioning, why I enabled versioning AFTER the mistake haha.

So no, otherwise I could have restored the working version :(

Comment: Then go for the upgrade, I'm adding an answer for that